# Xpath to locate the element of a day from the date picker

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automation

I have to click on day 11 on the calendar but I am unable to construct XPath to perform click operation on that particular date.

I am unable to copy-paste the HTML code here so kindly find the attached image for the HTML and please suggest suitable XPath.
[image]

Comment: Can you give us a link in order to check it ourselves? It would be much appreciated because we can give you the best option (dynamic)

Comment: @dpapadopoulos I do understand your concern but i am not supposed to share the link of our web application.Also the application can be accessed only at client server.So please help me out with any other alternate solution.

Comment: You need to click on the current day or clicking on a day by using the number of it?

Comment: @dpapadopoulos Clicking on a day by using number of it.

Comment: check my answer. It's in python. What lang are you using?

Comment: @dpapadopoulos i am using C#

Comment: okay, try my answer and tell me if it's fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**CODE**

```
day_that_you_want = "10"    
//td[contains(text(), day_that_you_want)]
```

Comment: It's probably more secure to be more specific. Something like : `//td[@class='day' and contains(text(), day_that_you_want)]`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to click on the active day, which is 11 in this case, you can fetch it using its class in the xpath.
Your should be:

```
//td[@class='active day']
```

Comment: Check the comment in his question: Clicking on a day by using number of it. So, it's day number related and not the current one